# How can I target this iframe CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

Thank you in advance.

I need help changing the CSS of this iframe.

They use inline !important so now on my CSS I cannot change it, so I need to use JavaScript, but all I can find is to use the "document.getElementsById" - however, the ID for this iframe is randomly generated on each page load making it impossible to target the ID of this element.

Can I target by the title as the title "Chat Widget" is the only thing that stays consistent on this iframe.

Thanks

Comment: Please provide a code snippet *in the question body* or a link to the page you're discussing if it's publicly open *in a comment here*. This will help other people understand exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Comment: The link is https://www.coversandbags-uk.com/ I need to move the chat widget up. If you inspect the iframe for chat you will find my bottom:50px is not overriding the bottom:20px !important  inlined. I need help to change this using .js.

Answer (score 0):

syntax :**`<iframe src="URL"></iframe>`**
There are several techniques to apply CSS property to an iframe
**`<iframe src=”www.stackoverflow.com” style=”border: 2px dotted; width: 200px; height: 300px;”> </iframe>`**

You can use the internal CSS for the iframe tag inside the HTML file.
and You can use external CSS for the iframe, which is making use of an external CSS file. Create a different file for the CSS code and include it in the HTML file using the link and href tag before the iframe tag.

Comment: Pretty sure he doesn't mean manually editing the CSS. He wants to edit the CSS through adding a .css / .js file without editing the HTML file itself (since he has no access to it, since it's server-rendered). Now adding a .css file cannot overrule the inline `!important` so he's thinking about a .js file.

Comment: This absolutely correct. The css is being provided by the server and I don't have direct access. I tried to add my own CSS on my end but as mmdts explained the !important inline are not allowing me to change anythings. .js appears to be my only option.